# How to create ad-hoc calculated column for SQLAlchemy model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say, I have a SQLAlchemy model:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
```

And I have a query:

```
session.query(User, (User.frist_name + ' ' + User.last_name).label('full_name')).all()
```

It will give me output, like `[(User(...), 'John Smith'), ...]`.

What I want to achieve is to make SQLAlchemy attach `full_name` to `User()` objects as an attribute for one-shot query. What is the best recipe for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a trigger to calculate a column `full_name` for each `INSERT`/`UPDATE` to your `User` model. Although I would suggest using [`hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property).

So you'd have something like this in your `User` model.

```
@hybrid_property
def full_name(self):
    # This is used for calculating the full name in python side.
    return '{0} {1}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

@full_name.expression
def full_name(cls):
    # This is an expression that gets executed as SQL.
    return cls.first_name.concat(' ').concat(cls.last_name)
```